# ng-change not working on ng-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a select box that is populated by the `ng-options`. Unfortunately, I cannot get my `ng-change` function to call.

[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/1097/)

Here is my `js`:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.typeOptions = [
    { name: 'Feature', value: 'feature' }, 
    { name: 'Bug', value: 'bug' }, 
    { name: 'Enhancement', value: 'enhancement' }
    ];

    $scope.scopeMessage = "default text";
    var changeCount = 0;

    $scope.onSelectChange = function()
    {
       changeCount++;
        this.message = "Change detected: " + changeCount;
    }.bind($scope);

    //$scope.form = {type : $scope.typeOptions[0].value};
    $scope.form = $scope.typeOptions[0].value;
}
```

And here is my `HTML`:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="row">
    <select ng-model='form' required ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions' ng-change="onSelectChange"></select>

    <div style="border:1px solid black; width: 100px; height:20px;">{{scopeMessage}}<div>
</div>
```

This is currently holding me up on my project for work, so any help will be geatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

2 things... both simple :)

1. `ng-change=onSelectChange` should be `onSelectChange()`
2. `this.message` should be `this.scopeMessage`

Comment: This one really should be the accepted answer. Testing the jsFiddle of user45763 shows that the text box doesn't change to say "Change detected" and it is for reason #2 in this answer by Timothy.

Comment: @MichaelMahony The question was "...I cannot get my ng-change function to call.". I was the first one to answer what was wrong, that's why it makes sense for my answer to be the accepted answer.

Comment: @user45763 I understand what you are saying, but when you read his code he wants the change to also change the textbox. To me a complete answer gets you all the way to the solution. Timonthy accomplished just that. Your answer was helpful, just not (in my humble opinion) complete.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't review this for an entire year. Yes @MichaelMahony you are correct. Time to fix things.

Comment: Woohoo! I got the accepted answer! Thanks @WebWanderer :)

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you are passing in the function reference to the ng-change directive. However, that directive expects an expression which can evaluated. So attach the parentheses to the function so that it can be evaluated as a function call.

Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/1101/

```
<select ng-model='form' required ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions' ng-change="onSelectChange()"></select>
```